# How to create multiple tableViews inside the same ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How do I load 2 (or more) tableViews inside the same ViewController? What I have now is:

```
- (void)reload {
    _products = nil;
    _products2 = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [[FlamencompasIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        //[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }];
    [self.tableView2 reloadData];
    [[FlamencompasIAPHelper sharedInstance2] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products2) {
        if (success) {
            _products2 = products2;
            [self.tableView2 reloadData];
        }
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }];
}
```

This code only loads the first tableView. I hope you know the solution for me.

Comment: Show your data provider methods.

Comment: Are you sure this block is executed on the main thead? reloadData should only be called on the main thread which is the ui thread.

Comment: Did you setup the `dataSource` and `delegate` for both table views? Do all of your data source and delegate methods properly handle both table views?

Comment: Do you mean the numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection methods?

Comment: @user1189952 Yes, those and others. Make sure each handles both table views assuming you set the same `dataSource` and `delegate` for both table views.

Comment: Which other methods do you mean?

Comment: The methods of the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.